# Efficient parsing of first four elements of large JSON arrays

Tags: json, jackson, gson, json-deserialization

I am using **Jackson** to parse JSON from a json `inputStream` which looks like following:

```
[
      [ 36,
        100,
        "The 3n + 1 problem",
         56717,
         0,
         1000000000,
         0,
         6316,
         0,
         0,
         88834,
         0,
         45930,
         0,
         46527,
         5209,
         200860,
         3597,
         149256,
         3000,
         1
      ],
      [
         ........
      ],
      [
         ........
      ],
         .....// and almost 5000 arrays like above
]
```

This is the original feed link: http://uhunt.felix-halim.net/api/p

I want to parse it and keep only the first 4 elements of every array and skip other 18 elements.

```
36
100
The 3n + 1 problem
56717
```

Code structure I have tried so far:

```
while (jsonParser.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_ARRAY) {

        jsonParser.nextToken(); // '['
        while (jsonParser.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_ARRAY) {
            // I tried many approaches here but not found appropriate one
         }

}
```

As this feed is pretty big, I need to do this efficiently with less overhead and memory. 
Also there are three models to procress JSON: **Streaming API**, **Data Binding** and **Tree Model**. Which one is appropriate for my purpose?

How can I parse this json efficiently with Jackson? How can I skip those 18 elements and jump to next array for better performance?

**Edit: (Solution)**

`Jackson` and `GSon` both works in almost in the same mechanism (incremental mode, since content is read and written incrementally), I am switching to `GSON` as it has a function `skipValue()` (pretty appropriate with name). Although Jackson's `nextToken()` will work like `skipValue()`, `GSON` seems more flexible to me. Thanks @Kowser bro for his recommendation, I came to know about GSON before but somehow ignored it. This is my working code:

```
reader.beginArray();
while (reader.hasNext()) {
   reader.beginArray(); 
   int a = reader.nextInt(); 
   int b = reader.nextInt();
   String c = reader.nextString();
   int d = reader.nextInt();
   System.out.println(a + " " + b + " " + c + " " + d);
   while (reader.hasNext())
      reader.skipValue();
   reader.endArray();
} 
reader.endArray();
reader.close();
```

Comment: Good luck with GSON, it's a decent library. I do not however see the point wrt `skipValue()` -- Jackson has `skipChildren()` that does the same, skipping the whole logical value (which for structured values consists of multiple tokens).

Comment: Please make sure that you put relevant details into the title. "Parsing JSON with Jackson" was in no way describing the specific problem you were having.

Comment: Also, when you [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), please post it as answer instead of editing it into the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is for `Jackson`

Follow [this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-streaming-api-to-read-and-write-json/).

Judicious use of jasonParser.nextToken() should help you.

```
while (jasonParser.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_ARRAY) { // might be JsonToken.START_ARRAY?
```

---

The pseudo-code is

1. find next array

   1. read values
   2. skip other values
   3. skip next end token

---

This is for `gson`.
Take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/gson-streaming-to-read-and-write-json/). Consider following second example from the tutorial.

Judicious use of `reader.begin*` `reader.end*` and `reader.skipValue` should do the job for you.

And here is the documentation for [JsonReader](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/stream/JsonReader.html)

Comment: vai, thanks for your answer! now it works! I edited my answer and added my solution, I used GSON at last.