# Parsing unnamed arrays with Jackson

Tags: json, parsing, jackson

Possible duplicates: [Use Jackson to parse and unnamed array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22232926/use-jackson-to-parse-and-unnamed-array), [Parsing JSON with Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18040368/parsing-json-with-jackson)

I have several files containing unnamed JSON arrays with the following structure:

[ {json stuff}, {json stuff}, ..., {json stuff} ]

However, `json stuff` varies greatly from file to file, and I already have code that could parse something like `"myJSONarray" : [ {json stuff}, {json stuff}, ..., {json stuff} ]`. The first step would be something like `myJSONarray.get(0) ...`Is there any way to use `get()` in order to get at the contents of the anonymous array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//read the JSON into myJSONFile (a JsonNode)
....
String s = myJSONFile.toString();
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

JsonNode actualObj = mapper.readTree(s);
JsonNode blah = actualObj.get(0);
```

actualObj can be used as if it was a key for the entire JSON file.